# VB.NET - How I can use this var like a RegEx?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I need to use a var called "caracter" as "Char" type like a regexp, in this example:

```
 If CheckboxN.Name.Contains(caracter) Then...
```

This is the interpretation of the example above in Ruby if someone don't understand my intentions:

```
If CheckboxN.Name[(/^#{Regexp.escape(caracter)}$/)] Then...
```

Thankyou for read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Regex.Match()` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match.aspx).

---

```
 Dim reg As New Regex(character)
 If reg.IsMatch(CheckboxN.Name) Then
     'Do Stuff...
 End If
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i've tried but i get this error:  If CheckboxN.Name.Contains(Regex.Match(caracter)) Then                 Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Comment: You didn't take a very good look. :)  Regex is not a static class, you have to create a new instance with the pattern you are looking for, and then use that to match against your string.

Comment: Use the example just as @bhamby wrote it.

Comment: thankyou you two, i accept your answer but if you can help me a little more (I'm begineer) i get this error with your last update: Error 1 'Text' is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types 'System, System.Drawing'.

Comment: You should be able to add `Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions` to the top of your code, and the error will go away. As the error says, there are multiple namespaces that it is finding `Text` in, so you need to make in unambiguous.

Comment: I've imported the reference before testing the bhamby example, i tested the new modification and i still getting a eror: Error 1 Value of type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match' cannot be converted to 'Boolean'.   Really thankyou for all

Comment: That's because it probably returns a Match object (also see the msdn link!! It contains all the information).

Comment: You need to use `reg.Match(input).Success` or `reg.IsMatch(input)`.